# Declaring the type of a deeply nested Map in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I cannot seem to figure out how to declare a deeply nested (recursive) Map in typescript in a generic way. As a starting point I am simply trying to convert the following Javascript example to Typescript

```
const o1 = new Map([
  ['a', 'A']
])
const o2 = new Map([
  ['b1', 'B'],
  ['b2', o1]
])

const o3 = new Map([
  ['c1', 'C'],
  ['c2', o2]
])

console.log('o3', o3)
```

Thanks

Comment: Something like? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCCMMC8MwFMDuMCyBDADgBQDaAsAFAwzEDkuNANDDQII0C6F7AlBRVAE98aGAGUoAJwCWYAOYB5CXnzIY0aXJgAfHAQA86mbKbiNCpQQB8fcqEiwQAJlXosyg5KMnPcxcsskFFS0AEbwjMwAQhwMQdQ0IY4RCJzkPDZ20HAAzC6YuvgeZt5mflaBlPHA4Uw0AMIxcbTASUxOqenkFJkgADZoAHS9ILKENCDZydncQA

Answer (score 0):

Typescript supports [recursive type references](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050), so we can describe map's value as:

```
type StringOrMap = string | Map<string, StringOrMap>
```

And specify it explicitly for `Map` constructor:

```
const o2 = new Map<string, StringOrMap>([
  ['b1', 'B'],
  ['b2', o1]
])

const o3 = new Map<string, StringOrMap>([
  ['c1', 'C'],
  ['c2', o2]
])
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCCMMC8MwFMDuMCyBDADgBQDaAsAFAwzEDkuNANDDQII0C6F7AlBRVAE98aGAGUoAJwCWYAOYB5CXnzIY0aXJgAfHAQA86mbKbiNCpQQB8fcqEiwQAJlXosyg5KMnPcxcsskFFS0AEbwjMwAQhwMQdQ0IY4RCJzkPDZ20HAAzC6YuvgeZt5mflaBlPHA4Uw0AMIxcbTASUxOqenkFJkgADZoAHS9ILKENCDZydncQA)